# Книга Лутца, 4 издание

Tags: python, книги

По поводу книги Лутца, 4 издание.

Я так понимаю, что большинство примеров для 2-й версии?

Comment: А я, кстати, думал палец вверх.

P.S. Вот и юзабилити в деталях.

Comment: @xmaster83, "палец вверх" означает -- "этот ответ мне нравится",

а вот "галка" -- "уверен, что этот ответ *действительно* все мне объясняет"  
(не знаю, можно ли отметить так несколько ответов или только один, но "палец вверх" и "галка" не противоречат друг другу).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все примеры кода в 4-х изданиях [книг о Питоне, написанных Марком Лутц](http://www.rmi.net/~lutz/#pubs), поддерживают 3-ю версию, некоторые также могут работать на Python 2.7. [Сайт](http://www.rmi.net/~lutz/) содержит ссылки на электронные версии примеров для разных изданий (свободный доступ).